# Android: Implementing a Back Button from a class

Tags: java, android, button, back

Okay, so here is my problem. I'm working on an android app and learning android at the same time, so most of the times I get errors. Normaly I can fix them after researching a bit, but I'm getting stuck in this point.

I'm trying to make a back button for every Activity in my app, so I thought about making a "BackButton" class, so I can instanciate it every time I want to. Here is my BackButton code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;

    public class BackButton extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

        public static Button BackButton;

        // Defining the button
        public BackButton() {

            BackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBack);

            BackButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        //To get the Button
        public static Button getBackButton() {
            return BackButton;
        }


        // OnClickListener
        public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    Class MainActivityClass = Class.forName("eu.lafarga.treballderecerca.MainActivity");
                    Intent MainActivityIntent = new Intent(BackButton.this, MainActivityClass); 
                    startActivity(MainActivityIntent);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    // Save the things we've done. 
                }

        }

    }
```

So, how should I implement this in any activity? I'm doind something wrong? (Sure I'm lol)

Comment: Well dont override the back button, if you still need then instantiate an object of the class you have made inside on back pressed method.

Comment: if you merely want back button functionality then why don't you use action bar http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html

Comment: you don't need a back button you have a hardware back button when clicked takes you back to the previous activity. For navigation use actionbar and navigationbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would suggest not doing this. I think overriding the back button in each `Activity` would be safer, more flexible, and just as easy, if not easier. Chances are, you aren't always going to want to return to the `MainActivity` as your app grows because its likely that this won't be the expected action for the users when they hit the back button. Override the back button in `Activities` that need it and run your code

```
    @Overrride
    public void onBackPressed(View v) {
     // save data first

      Intent MainActivityIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, MainActivityClass); 
      startActivity(MainActivityIntent);
      super.onBackPressed();
}
```

You can also use flags such as `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` if you want to remove all `Activities` between the current one and the target `Activity`(here `MainActivity`) by calling `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)`

Answer (score 4):

There is a easier way to Listen to the backButton.

```
// Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key.
 onBackPressed()
```

And when you do not call the super-method, there shouldn't be any further steps.
But it is not a good way to "disable" the back-button.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to block back button.

By overriding `onKeyDown` or `onBackPressed` of your `Activity`.

Please visit following question link for detailed description and its solution given in answer.

[**Link 1**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969541/override-back-button-in-android)

[**Link 2**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity)